# Switch case with data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-switch

Previously I had created an interface with two button implemented data binding to have a case when button A clicked then Shows input 1, if button B clicked then show input 1+2. Something similar to selected flight trip (one way or return).

[image: Image case 1]

the structure I use for this is a boolean

`android:onClick="@{() -> view.selectTripType(true)}"`

`android:onClick="@{() -> view.selectTripType(false)}"`

and in my fragment is create a function with

```
 public void selectTripType(boolean isRound) {
        viewModel.setRoundTrip(isRound);
        if (isRound) {
            setTripBtnStyle(binding.fragmentBusmainBtnroundtrip, binding.fragmentBusmainBtnoneway);
            binding.fragmentBusmainReturndateT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            setTripBtnStyle(binding.fragmentBusmainBtnoneway, binding.fragmentBusmainBtnroundtrip);
            binding.fragmentBusmainReturndateT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to add another button which will have 3rd case, can I use a switch case in a data binding or how should I create for this?

[image: 3button with differences case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using some integer value?

```
android:onClick="@{() -> view.selectTripType(1)}"

android:onClick="@{() -> view.selectTripType(2)}"

android:onClick="@{() -> view.selectTripType(3)}"
```

and in your function

```
public void selectTripType(int type) {
    // 1 : one way
    // 2 : round
    // 3 : disposal
}
```